# Do we really need "marvel-unlimited" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag wiki:

> For questions about Marvel Unlimited, an online service that distributes Marvel Comics. It was launched in 2007.

There are 4 questions tagged with this. Two of these are wrongly tagged:

[When and why did the Marvel Universe start to have alternative Universes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107267/when-and-why-did-the-marvel-universe-start-to-have-alternative-universes)

[How has magic changed in the Marvel Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/169594/how-has-magic-changed-in-the-marvel-universe)

Other two are correctly tagged, but one is closed. Do we really need the [marvel-unlimited](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-unlimited) tag?

Besides, does this tag really adhere to the policies of this site?

Comment: I vaguely remember in one tag cleanup event suggesting removing a "shop" tag (think it was comixology), and was rejected.  So yeah, they're valid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *if* (big if, see bold text below) there's at least one valid question specifically about an aspect of that service.

Of the two where it clearly didn't apply, I removed the tag. Of the other two, one is already closed. The last one is this:

[Marvel Unlimited - comics aimed at young children](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36655/marvel-unlimited-comics-aimed-at-young-children)

To me, this feels like a shopping question. It's asking for details about shopping for a service. Sure, it's a *specific* service, but it's still a shopping question. The answer could very well be outdated considering it's an ongoing, changing service.

It's akin to asking "Is X show available on Netflix?" which is off-topic.

**So, in my opinion, this last question should probably be closed as off-topic, and then the tag removed from the closed questions as it's not really necessary. But, so long as we decide to keep that question open, the tag fits.**

---

If tag is to stick around, I would expect a more appropriate use to be asking stuff about Marvel Unlimited related to the general Marvel fandom or the company, rather than just general "can I read X on Marvel Unlimited" questions. For example "Why did Marvel launch Marvel Unlimited?" or "Are some comics released exclusively on Marvel Unlimited (and not in print)?"

Comment: The question seems a reasonable one. A month has gone by and this is the only answer. It has had no downvotes, but only one upvote (mine - today). That doesn't seem enough to constitute consensus. I hope others will chime in, or at least vote.

Comment: @Blackwood The problem is most people don't care about such small tagging issues like this. Sometimes we just need to make executive decisions that follow best practices, we don't need a full community overview.